# Deutsche Bahn: Boarding train at an earlier stop than what’s stated in the itinerary?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

I bought a Super Sparpreis ticket from Konstanz-Petershausen to Nuremberg. The first leg is an RE train while the next is an IC.

There’s a possibility I might have to board the RE train at Konstanz Hbf instead, which is the stop/station before Konstanz-Petershausen (about 2 mins apart) on the same train route.

Will my Super Sparpreis ticket be valid even though I boarded at an earlier stop?

Edited to add: On the Deutsche Bahn app, Ticket section (where the QR code is) shows Verbindung Konstanz-Nürnberg. Itinerary section shows Konstanz-Petershausen to Nürnberg Hbf.

Comment: Do you have/intend to get a ticket for that short leg? Because DB is trying to give me a 22€ ticket for that connection

Comment: Your ticket is valid, as explained [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78430/67683).

Comment: (The actual link in that answer is dead, I've submitted an edit to replace that with an up-to-date one, but it's not visible yet.)

Comment: Actually, I've reread the relevant documents, and it's a bit slimey still. I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: In practice you will _likely_ be waived through regardless of the actual rules, should you happen to be checked in that 2 minute window. If you want to improve your chances there, approach the conductor proactively and tell them you've had to board a station earlier because reasons, and ask them to sell you an extra ticket for this one stop. I would think that _most_ conductors would just tell you that it's fine; worst case they'll actually sell you the extra ticket for some €2 or however much it is.

Comment: What exactly is stated as the "from" location on the ticket?

Comment: @asdfex on the Ticket part of the DB Bahn app: Verbindung Konstanz-Nürnberg. Itinerary part shows Konstanz-Peterhausen  to Nürnberg Hbf.

Comment: To reiterate my above comment: that's a 400km+, ~6h journey, which you have fully paid for. Even if it was against the rules, it would be _extremely_ petty of any conductor to fine you for having the gall to board the train some 2km/2m early. Not that such conductors don't exist, mind you…

Comment: What matters is what is stated on the "ticket part" on the top. The itinerary part is just for your convenience.

Answer (score 5):

I claim that your ticket is valid for boarding on the earlier station, for somewhat obscure reasons.

Namely, in this particular case, the two stations are considered equivalent for tariff purposes, as can be seen in the [*Liste der gleichgestellten Tarifpunkte*](https://www.bahn.de/faq/was-ist-unter-der-tariflichen-gleichstellung-zu-verstehen-und-ist-diese-auch-bei-sparpreis-tickets-gueltig) published by Deutsche Bahn (see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78430/67683) for an explanation of how to read this table). However, in itself, this only tells us that, if you had booked a ticket starting at Konstanz Hbf, you would've paid the same as you did for the ticket starting at Konstanz-Petershausen.

However, if you take into account the exact details of the ticket, I'd guess that you'll find that the ticket does give you this little bit of flexibility. To illustrate, I'll use an example from an earlier trip of mine, where I booked a Super Sparpreis Europa ticket from Braunschweig Hbf to Zwolle, but wanted to start my trip at Braunschweig-Gliesmarode. In my case, this required taking a separate regional train from Braunschweig-Gliesmarode to Braunschweig Hbf.

I reasoned as follows:

- in the Deutsche Bahn Navigator app, the trip details are split into two tabs: Ticket and Itinerary. One would assume that you're bound to what's written on the ticket, and not to any details in only present in the itinerary.
- the ticket listed the following:

  > **Gültigkeit**
  > ICE Fahrkarte (Einfache Fahrt)
  > Super Sparpreis Europa
  > 2. Klasse
  > 1 Person [age details elided]
  > Von: 31.10.2023, 00:00 Uhr
  > Bis: 02.11.2023, 03:00 Uhr
  >
  > **Verbindung**
  > Braunschweig - Zwolle
  > Zugbindung: ICE 754, 17:56 Uhr
  > Via:
  > <1080>LEHR*H*WUNS*MI*LOEH*BUEN*OS*RHEI*Bad Bentheim(Gr)<1184>Regional Train*Hengelo

  saying that the ticket is valid during a 2-day period starting at midnight, on journeys from Braunschweig (exact station unspecified) to Zwolle, as long as you make use of the ICE 754 leaving at 17:56 (which is the leg of the trip from Hannover to Osnabrück, and obey the [routing instructions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/132844/67683).
- notably, the ticket only lists the *Sammelbezeichnung* (collective designation) for the stations involved (see linked PDF), thus the ticket is valid whether I start my journey as Braunschweig Hbf, or Braunschweig-Gliesmarode.

Now, your case might be different, but I would assume that as long as your ticket says "Konstanz – Nürnberg" as opposed to "Konstanz-Petershausen – Nürnberg Hbf" in the Verbindung section,<sup>[1]</sup> has its validity starting at midnight and doesn't list the regional train in the Zugbindung for some reason, then you're in the clear.

The caveat is that the ultimate test of this logic is what a Deutsche Bahn employee would say, and I haven't had the opportunity of them checking my ticket at a moment that would confirm or deny my logic.<sup>[2]</sup>

Worst case, the likelihood that your ticket will get checked during these two minutes is very low. And if it does happen, you can always say "huh? the ticket doesn't differentiate between the two stations, look!" ;3

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I suspect that this is the case when the distance traveled exceeds the distance minimum listed in *Liste der gleichgestellten Tarifpunkte*, which – in your case – is 101 km.

<sup>[2]</sup>  <del>I did have my ticket checked at a different moment, that confirmed that a different point of flexibility – being able to use an earlier regional train than the booked – is accepted, either because it's indeed valid, or because they don't care to enforce it. In the latter case I would've expected at least a comment about my deviation from the itinerary, though.</del> Looks like that is very explicitly allowed:

> **Which trains can I travel on?**
>
> If you have a saver fare ticket, you can only travel on the service indicated on the ticket. Offers are available for ICE/IC/EC connections within Germany. You can use local transport (e.g. RE, RB, IRE and S-Bahn or non-DB trains) to get to/from a long-distance station if you include them in your booking. You are not restricted to travelling on a specific train when using local rail services. However, your journey must be completed by 10:00 am the following day.
>
> – [FAQ on the Super Sparpreis fare](https://int.bahn.de/en/faq/super-saver-fare-ticket-trains-9-90)

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, you booked a ticket between two stations served by an ICE and that's what you got, I don't follow how this gives us any clue on how to interpret the rules. Especially when you consider how annoying DB is getting with the City Tickets rule, I see no reasons to believe that any leeway is intended. If you want to risk it (as you said, it's very short), I would rather plead ignorance or confusion that try to lecture the train guard on the “rules”.

Comment: @Relaxed In my case the itinerary involved a regional train, followed by an ICE, followed by another three regional trains.

Comment: I just checked a recent print-at-home ticket. It does say “Sie können alle Züge nutzen, die auf Ihrer Fahrkarte angegeben sind. Für Züge des Nahverkehrs (z.B. RE, RB, S) besteht keine Zugbindung.” which seems to support your interpretation and explains why the train guard didn't care that you were on another regional train. Still, I find it hard to reconcile with what I have been reading, especially regarding the City Ticket. Note that both your ticket and the one I just checked are Super Sparpreis Europa, technically yet another type of ticket if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Relaxed I assume you're referring to [this](https://www.bahn.de/faq/buchung-city-ticket-sp-ssp-10-12-23). If I'm reading it correctly, it doesn't actually say anything about some kind of limited City-Ticket for only getting to a particular transit stop. It just says, if you type in something that's not a train station, you'll be presented offers that combine the cheaper Super Sparpreis no-cancellation tickets with the City-Ticket.

Comment: AFAIK It matters what exactly is printed on the ticket. If a station is named explicitly the ticket is valid from this station only. If the name of the city is given (usually in capital letters), then the ticket is valid from any DB train station in that city.

Comment: @Maya Yes indeed but that's not how I read it. See especially “Bei der Buchung des (Super) Sparpreis Tickets ist es künftig wichtig, die konkrete Start- und Zielhaltestelle anzugeben.” In other words, you cannot get the (free) benefit of a City-Ticket if you haven't specifically mentioned the exact transit stop you want to use. Zero flexibility, zero leeway, even if, as you point out, the train ticket itself doesn't even mention regional trains or a specific station.

Comment: @Maya I edited my post to add that on the Deutsche Bahn app, Ticket section shows Verbindung Konstanz-Nürnberg. Itinerary section shows Konstanz-Petershausen to Nürnberg Hbf.

Comment: Also note this: “Wenn hingegen laut Buchungsanfrage ausschließlich Züge des DB Fernverkehrs benötigt werden (z.B. von Köln Hbf nach Berlin Hbf) und somit kein Umstieg innerhalb des City-Ticket-Gebietes in den öffentlichen Nahverkehr erfolgt, ist das City-Ticket auch beim Sparpreis nicht mehr inklusive.” In other words, even S-Bahn, RE and RB trains are *not* included by default, only mainline services (*Fernverkehr*). It also suggest the connection you requested (*Buchungsanfrage*) does matter and not only the ticket.

Comment: @Relaxed Don't confuse the City ticket and the "gleichgestellten Tarifpunkte". These are completely different concepts.

Comment: @janny27 That seems to mean that Mayas answer applies to your ticket. There's no name of a station but a "collective designation" for all DB stations in Konstanz.

Comment: This answer is correct, "tarifliche Gleichstellung" is the key here. Official source is the linked table together with [this PDF](https://assets.static-bahn.de/dam/jcr:55326ab8-ba1a-442a-ab3e-ab54d083f592/1%28%20Vorbemerkungen.pdf) section 2.7, where it says "Sie bewirkt, dass relationsbezogene Fahrkarten von oder zu verschiedenen Bahnhöfen innerhalb einer tariflichen Gleichstellung zu einem einheitlichen Preis erstellt werden und diese Fahrkarten dementsprechend beliebig von/nach einem dieser Bahnhöfe genutzt werden können." It also mentions that this is valid for (Super) Sparpreis.

Comment: @asdfex I am aware of the difference, I mentioned both, separately, in my answer. But it still doesn't make sense to me to assume so much flexibility in one case when DB is explicit that (Super) Sparpreis tickets are intended to be much more restrictive. Importantly, the “gleichgestellten Tarifpunkte” is about the price for a given route, not the specific trains you can use. For a full fare, flexible ticket, there is obviously no difference as a ticket is in principle valid on any train on a given route but for a (Super) Sparpreis ticket, there is a difference.

Comment: @asdfex That's why I brought up the quote in my last comment. Beyond the specific product, DB clearly intends discounted tickets to be much more restrictive than the routing info printed on the ticket itself (the kind of things you rely on when considering “gleichgestellten Tarifpunkte”). In that context, treating only this as binding and the itinerary as a mere suggestion seems a bit self-serving and risky.

Comment: The document found by @PhilippWendler does suggest I am wrong about that, though. Curious to see how it will be updated after the rule changes. Or maybe they will just stop issuing discounted tickets with more generic “Sammelbezeichnung“ as a way to implement the new restrictions.

Comment: @Relaxed do note that Sparpreis is specifically an offer for long-distance trains, and only includes a Zugbindung for the long-distance trains you're supposed to use as part of your journey. The RE/RB part is still flexible.

Comment: @Maya Yes, I even copy-pasted a sentence explaining that when you were still confused about it. But the new City-Ticket rules highlight that DB is going out of its way to add restrictions on the itinerary, even the part where there is obviously no *Zugbindung*.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, your ticket is not valid for the short trip between the main station and Petershausen. In many cases, it is actually possible to do something like that with a Sparpreis ticket through the [City-Ticket concept](https://www.bahn.de/angebot/weiterreise/city-ticket) but it does not apply to *Super* Sparpreis tickets.

From December 10, 2023, the rules are changing for discounted tickets. After that date, a city trip can be included in a Super Sparpreis ticket but you need to name the exact stop or station when booking the ticket. The same rules will also apply to Sparpreis tickets (so you're losing a bit of flexibility there).

Your best bet if you want some peace of mind in this case is simply to get a [local transportation ticket for one zone](https://www.vhb-info.de/fahrkarten/) for €2.80. It is also valid on RE trains as long as you stay within one single zone within the area covered by the Verkehrsverbund Hegau-Bodensee, which is the case for the Petershausen-Hauptbahnhof trip.

---

Rules for full fare tickets are quite different. In this case, as explained in [Board German train from next station](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78371/board-german-train-from-next-station), all the stations within the city are treated as equivalent. On top of that, you are also allowed to make use of local public transit in Konstanz on the day you leave or arrive there, without having to mention it when booking the ticket.

Comment: About the City ticket rule change: In most cases you are gaining options instead of losing. I.e. there was no City ticket for SuperSparpreis before, there was no City ticket for short full-fare trips, and for Sparpreis tickets you need to precisely state start and end of the journey, but it's optional.  Only Sparpreis tickets lose some flexibility because you have to decide at the time of booking.

Comment: @asdfex Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: No contradiction, just a few more details.